# Can anyone explain the connection between absolutely continuous functions on R and absolutely continuous measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Can anyone explain the connection between absolutely continuous functions on R and absolutely continuous measure? I think the connection is also relevant to radon nikodym derivatives and fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Also, see the relevant [section on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Relation_between_the_two_notions_of_absolute_continuity).

Comment: You might want to read Chapter 6 and 7 of Rudin's RCA.

Answer (score 2):

A measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure $m$ if and only if the function $F\left(x\right)=\mu\left(\left(-\infty,x\right]\right)$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: That second $F$ can actually just be $L^1$ (and nonnegative, if you want $\mu$ to be a measure instead of a signed measure).

Comment: In your last sentence, what is the measure absolutely continuous with respective to?

Comment: It would be absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure. @user1559897

Comment: You're right, I deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

An absolutely continuous function is, in probability terminology, the "CDF" of a (perhaps signed) measure which is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure. By that I mean that if $F : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is absolutely continuous then $F(x)=\mu([a,x])$ where $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure. (It could be that $a=-\infty$ and/or $b=+\infty$.) The Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ with respect to Lebesgue measure is the ordinary derivative of $F$.

Comment: Can you add some explanation as to why such claims hold?

Comment: @user1559897 The fundamental theorem of calculus tells you that $F(x)=\int_a^x f(y) dy$ where $f$ is the derivative of $F$. Define that to be your measure $\mu$, then argue that if $A_n$ are measurable sets with $m(A_n) \to 0$ then $\mu(A_n) \to 0$ (you can do this with, for instance, the bounded convergence theorem).